# Is it an expensive operation to create the IOS Core Data Model objects?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have been avoiding use of the IOS Core Data Model and now have a question of efficiency.  If I want to check the count of my table frequently and at random parts of my App.  I want to know if creating the context, entity, and fetch-request for this "count" method, like this, is light-weight or expensive.  If it is expensive, which ones can I set as properties and create-once or make as singletons, etc.  I fear that the dynamic nature of the Data Model could require fresh working objects.

```
-(NSInteger) count {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MdCoreDataModel sharedInstance] contextFortune];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"MyTable" inManagedObjectContext: context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger countTotal = [context countForFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: &error];

    if (error) {
        NSString *stringErrorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]];
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, stringErrorMsg);
        countTotal = 0;

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Debug" message: stringErrorMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    return countTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know core data is very quick, the WWDC core data best practice videos provide info on this and how to use instruments to check speed etc.